# How to break while loop at a certain index but then run until end of a list?

Tags: python

I have the code below, I wish to run the while loop to remove a specific value from the list but not remove it on a certain index and still loop through the whole list without removing that specific occurrence.

```
a = 20
i = [5, 15, 20, 25, 50, 20, 80, 90, 20]
while a in i:
   i.remove(a)
    if a == i.index(5):
       continue
  print(i)
```

Maybe it's not supposed to be done with while loop but since learning the break or continue functions, i thought to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly don’t alter a collection as you are iterating through it. Secondly use a different name for the current item. eg use ‘item’.

Comment: `while i in i`?

Comment: use a for loop instead of a while loop, and don't alter the list while traversing through it.

Answer (score 7):

Typically something you can solve with a list comprehension:

```
[ el for i, el in enumerate(lst) if i == 3 or el != 25]
```

Creates a new list while looping over the original one and adds all the elements that are not 25 (the one you want to remove) but still adds it if i==3, the position that is protected.